# iPhone5 simulator not appearing in xcode 4.5 preview (4G78z)

Tags: xcode

I have xcode 4.5 preview installed on Mountain Lion. When I go to hardware-->Device, I have the iPhone retina option but no option for iPhone retina-4inch. Do I need to upgrade my xcod e or install anything else to have the iphone retina 4-inch simulator?

[image: Here is the screen shot of ios 6 simulator and the options I have in hardware-->Device]

Comment: Did you get this solved ? Post your answer so that others visiting your Q can also solve them

Comment: I installed the latest Xcode (Xcode 4.5.2) from the developer.apple.com. This versions has simulator for iPhone retina-4inch

Comment: I also did the same and now I do have simulator for iphone 5 :)